# Is type that defined by 'typedef' visible outside the file?

Tags: c

http://en.literateprograms.org/Red-black_tree_(C)
I got this link and found 
this definition.

`typedef rbtree_node node;
typedef enum rbtree_node_color color;`

It is said to be private definition.

I am confused about private property,does it mean the `node` and `color` only visible in the file and won't propagate to other files,or just for convenience?

Comment: There is no private propery in c, there are opaque types which this might be one. What you might need to read about is **scope**.

Comment: No, it's just pointing out that the types shouldn't be used outside of the functions that implement the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be "private" if the `typedef` would be placed inside a body file. And "public" when it would be placed inside a header file. Private and public don't really exist in C, what they are probably talking about is scope.